# pass HTML to phantom and render it to PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

Normally in phantom you would be able to do something like this:

```
phantom = require('phantom')


phantom.create(function(ph){
  ph.createPage(function(page) {
    page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
      page.render('google.pdf', function(){

        console.log('Page Rendered');
        ph.exit();

      });
    });
  });
});
```

However instead of loading a webpage i already have some html i want to pass and render as a PDF.

How would i be able to just pass it `HTML` and convert it to `PDF` and is `PhantomJs` the right appraoch for this or is `ffmpeg` a better approach and if so how do i use `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`content` property of the page](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html).

```
phantom = require('phantom')
phantom.create(function(ph){
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.content = "Some html"//Set your html here
        page.render('google.pdf', function(){
            console.log('Page Rendered');
            ph.exit();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does not work in current version. (there is just a blank page)

Answer (score 0):

Phantom is no longer supported.
I suggest to use puppeteer from the Chrome DevTools team. The code is much cleaner and readable:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`<p>Hello world!</p>);
  // alternatively it can be fetched from web
  // await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```